# Animation not working as expected

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to perform a fade out and then face in animation but the view just becomes invisible for the duration of the animation and then reappears.

`fade_out_in.xml`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    >
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="200" />
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="200"
        android:startOffset="200" />
</set>
```

code:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out_in);
    mImageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: I think you have to create separate file for fade in and fade out animation

Answer (score 2):

I cant exactly tell you why this is not working, but it seems that multiple alpha animations dont work in an XML < set > . You can either combine them to one alpha like this :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

or cut the xml and do it with an [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) like in Rubin's answer. 
Another possibility would be to use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) :

```
    final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    mImageView.animate()
            .alpha(0)
            .setDuration(200)
            .setStartDelay(500)
            .setInterpolator(interpolator)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mImageView.animate()
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(200)
                        .setInterpolator(interpolator);
                }
            });
```

note here that the .withEndAction() call requires MIN API 16.

Answer (score 1):

please try that code

```
 Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);


    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    this.setAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Please explain why problem exists,not just instead solution.